# Explore database contents from .sql file

Tags: mysql

I inherited the maintenance of a small web forum. Near as I can tell, it is powered by a MySQL database on the backend (the frontend is all PHP).

I need to extract some of the data (which also involves searching for the data I need to extract), but I don't want to touch the production database. I exported a database backup, which produced a several-hundred-megabyte .sql file.

What's the best way to mine these data? I can see several options:

- grep through the .sql script in text mode, trying to extract the relevant data
- Load it up in sqlite3 (I tried doing this, but it barfed on some of the statements in the script and didn't produce any tables. I have no database experience whatsoever though, so I haven't ruled it out as a dead end just yet).
- Install MySQL on my home box, create a database, and execute the .sql script to recreate the data. Then just attach some database explorer tool.
- Find some (Linux) app which can understand the .sql file natively (seems unlikely after a bit of Googling).

Any pointers to which of these options (or one I haven't thought of yet) would be the most productive?

Comment: Unless the .sql dump was a multi-db dump, you can reimport the contents into a different db, leaving the production stuff unchanged.

Comment: You probably want to import it into an instance of mysql. Whether that's your home box, a different db on the production server, a shared hosting account, etc. is pretty much your call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say any option might work but for data mining, you definitely want to load it up in a new database so you can start query-ing the data and building reports on the data. I would load it up on your Home box. No need to have it remote.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think this solution is the best? I'm not super experienced with MySQL, and all I want to do is get some data out of the database (I realize I maybe shouldn't have used the term "data mining", since that can mean different things to different folks). So I'm trying to find the answer that's the right fit for me personally.

Comment: Hi Nathan. Sorry for the delay here. MySQL is a fairly straight forward DB to install and setup. Just download and install the community edition server:
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Install the GUI tools:

Comment: Install the GUI tools:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

I imagine you will be parsing the file and trying to make sense of it. The problem is the .sql file is mostly SQL code which you will spend most of your time trying to eliminate - whereas you could take a few moments, probably less time, to setup a copy of your database and just browse the tables and data more productively. This will also give you more flexibility in managing the data. 

I might also be a good/fun exercise considering you are responsible for a MySQL DB and it will no doubt be beneficial to know how to manage it